# Maven build in Jenkins writes the output of execution to a file

Tags: maven, logging, jenkins

I have a Maven build job in Jenkins and in the **"Build"** section, I have given Maven Version and Root POM and in the **"Goals and Options"** filed, I am executing the pom with customized goals. I need to write the output of the execution to a file, I tried below

```
clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -nsu -l output.log
clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -nsu -DoutputFile=output.log
clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -nsu -Doutput=output.log
```

Nothing works for me. Could anyone please help in either the above way or any other option available to direct the output log to a file?

Answer (score 0):

According to `mvn -help`, the following works for me:

```
clean install -l output.log
```

The file is stored to the job workspace, if you want to publish it as an artifact, you need to add a Publish artifact or Publish document post-step (or Publish document post-build option in Maven project).